# How to synchronize iis between 2008r2 64bit to 2008 32 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, synchronization

Does anyone know of a way to synchronize iis between 2008r2 64bit to 2008 32 bit.
Msdeploy doesn't seem to like going from 64bit to 32 bit. :(

Update: 
The command I'm running is this (on 2008 32 bit):

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver,computerName=remote -dest:webserver

Output is:
Error: Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider webServer is not supported

Comment: Can you fully describe what happens when you try to use MSDeploy? What commands you run, what your environment is set up like, and what results you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I sort of managed to get it to work. 
The trick is to use msdeploy.exe from Program Files(x86) on 64 bit 2008 r2 server, and run sync from there TO 32 bit 2008.

Also, since there is no AppWarmup module on 2008 server you have to add:  -skip:attributes.name="AppWarmupModule"

It's not ideal, since I'd prefer to run it the other way around, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say sync IIS. Would you be interested in replicating the websites physical files?

If so check out DFS as it can span 32 and 64 bit systems you just need a domain.

It is VERY easy to setup and works great! I use it to sync our constantly changing social network between two servers. I sync user files as well as new launches of the site from the production server to the standby server.

[Here is a link to the technet overview.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Hope that helps. May be a lot simpler this way. But may not be what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately the machines are not on the same domain (not even on the same LAN).

Comment: Are you looking for a real (or near real) time sync?

Comment: just a sync when I run the command. doesn't need to be realtime.

Comment: This is for files or IIS settings of the actual websites?

Comment: for everything. msdeploy works now the other way around, as I described above